# ASP.NET MVC - HttpException visible in View Source in browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I developed an asp.net mvc application. In one of my forms, I'm getting a following
exception:

A public action method 'UpdateBasket' could not be found on controller 'App.Controllers.WebShopController'

But the funny thing is, that form submit works (even in debug mode) and finds an
ActionMethod UpdateBasket and returns View. 
The problem is that because of that html generated error 
w3c validators and google crawlers can't access the site (I think so, correct me if I'm wrong).

Has anybody got any idea why this error occurs? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using Google Chrome to view the page source and you're encountering its tendency to reissue a "get" request for a post-only URL that your browser just "post"-ed to?
[This is the best description](http://eufuckingreka.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/the-idiosyncracies-of-google-chrome-view-source/) I've found.